# How do I connect raw end CAt5 Cable to existing router?

Tags: internet

Cat5 cable with bare end is at the internet drop box and I need to connect to my existing router that's inside the house where the internet cable is connected to an ARRIS modem, then to a Netgear router.

The cat5 cable then runs to an outbuilding where I plan to connect the raw end of the CAT5 cable to a router with an RJ45 connector (8p8c)

Comment: I think the cheapest and easiest way for diy is to purchase a single port and punch it down, some ports come with a plastic punchdown tool. Then you only need a short patch cable. If you want to purchase the crimp tool and some ends , you will probably need a few extras it’s not that hard but getting it right can take a time or two. The punch down ports are a lot easier and if you mess up you can pull the wire out and start over.

Answer (score 4):

The *correct* way to terminate fixed network cables is to a Jack (female.) Then you use a factory made patch cable (male-to-male) to connect to whatever you are connecting to.

You can buy tool-less jacks, or jacks that come with a cheap plastic "110" punch tool that is good enough for a few jacks, rather than investing in a nice spring-loaded steel "110" punch/cut tool. You'll have to nip the ends off with wirecutters, not a big deal for only a few jacks.

If you crimp Plugs (male) onto fixed cables, expect eventual failures.

Unless your cable is ancient, it's probably Cat5e, not Cat5 - Cat5 cable has not been produced for over a decade.

Running copper network cables to outbuildings tends to lead to fried equipment after thunderstorms. Using all-dielectric fiber instead leads to networking that just works. *Not* using specifically **rated for wet use** cables for either also leads to eventual failures.

Answer (score 1):

You need to terminate the Cat5 cable.  Either hire someone to come in and do it, or buy a kit (which contains all the necessary tools) to do it yourself.  If you're handy at all, buy a kit, watch some YouTube videos on how to do it, and go for it.  Just make sure to get the right termination plugs, as they are different depending on whether it's Cat5, or Cat6 cable.  Make sure to leave plenty of extra wire, as it will probably take at least a few tries the first time to get it right and you don't want to end up with not enough to put more ends on if needed.

Or the easiest option would probably be to find a friend who has the tools and experience to do this, and there's a pretty good chance they'd do it for a favorite beverage or pizza.